# Exec alternative in this case?

Tags: python, exec

- I have a secret dictionary. {'e':'3'}
- The user tells me the key and some operations that I can not predict in advance (int(e)+4)
- I need to return that.
  .
- currently I ask user for a string of python code similar to a jinja template. ('int({{e}}+4')
- I solve {{e}} = e
- I then return(exec('int('e')+4'))

The only other way I can think of is to share my dict values with user and let user perform their operations.

Think of it this way:

- I give user a value(password) based on their key(username)
- The user encrypts the number using their choice of operations
- I take the encrypted value and move it forward

Any other way to handle this?

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can often be used to replace `exec()`.